# Callback function does not change value of local variables (ROS)

Tags: python, ros

So I have a problem that asks me to rotate my robot facing the wall. I created a callback function for my subscriber and I am trying to compute its values in the function.
Here is the code:

```
def callback(msg):
  r = list(msg.ranges)
  minimum_value = min(r)
  print(minimum_value)
  index_minimum = r.index(minimum_value)
  rounded_min = round(minimum_value,3)
  print('min index',index_minimum)

  if index_minimum > 360:
      twist_instance.angular.z = 0.05
  else:
      twist_instance.angular.z = -0.05
  while round(msg.ranges[360],3) != rounded_min:
      print('rounded min', rounded_min)
      print('front ',round(msg.ranges[360],3))
      print('index naya', index_minimum)
      pub.publish(twist_instance)
      rate.sleep()
  twist_instance.linear.x = 0.1
  twist_instance.angular.z = 0
  while round(msg.ranges[360],1) >= 0.3:
      pub.publish(twist_instance)
      rate.sleep()
  twist_instance.linear.x = 0
  pub.publish(twist_instance)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('findwall_node')
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, callback)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)    
    twist_instance = Twist()
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    my_service = rospy.Service('/find_wall', findwall, my_callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

I am printing out the values just for a reference. Here the r = list(msg.ranges) has index range from 0 to 719 and they represent laser values from 0 to 180 degrees respectively. As the robot rotates the values will change at the same time but thats the problem I face. They do not!. I printed out the values in the loop and the values for each of them always remain constant.
Can you help me understand why that is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are using a loop inside the callback, in the line `while round(msg.ranges[360],3) != rounded_min`. Then, the callback gets "stuck", and it is called only once, causing `msg.ranges` to remain constant. However, I am not able to test your code just now.

Comment: This is correct. `rounded_min` will only be calculated once. Even if it was called more than once(it won’t be), that variable is local to the function.

Comment: and what of msg.ranges[360], this is the range of the front laser. While the robot is rotating the front laser range should change as well, for every time the loop is iterated. Why is that this value remains unchnaged too?

Comment: oh I get it. Then how do I compute the `msg.ranges` values for every loop interation?

Comment: @Mojiz you should remove the while loop. Instead you should save each individual range in a variable that isn’t local to the callback, and run your calculations every time you get a new message.

Comment: Why cant I write `msg.ranges` within the while loop so that it computes for evry iteration? I did that and it still gives me same result.

Comment: You need to exit the callback, for enabling the system to call it again with a different scan